# Is there an archive of IBMQ calibration data?

Tags: ibm-q-experience

Specifically, I'd like to see the `ibmq_london` calibration file for April 15, 2020.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Historical calibration data are available for each device via the `backend.properties()` method. It accepts a `datetime` field.

```
from datetime import datetime

t = datetime(day=15, month=4, year=2020, hour=10)
london_backend.properties(datetime=t)
```