# How to get pulse-level historical calibration data for OpenPulse devices?

Tags: ibm-quantum-devices

I see that there is a way to access historical IBM backend properties such as gate errors and gate lengths (discussed [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11754/is-there-an-archive-of-ibmq-calibration-data)). Is there any way to also get pulse-level historical calibration data for OpenPulse devices, such as calibrated pulse amplitudes (the info contained in backend.defaults())?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, this type of historical data is not accessible. The best approach is for the user to save it themselves if they would like to use the data in the future.